# Where is bootloader entry point for making android a very simple kiosk?

Tags: android-source, android-build

I have the latest android source downloaded and compiling and I’m trying to do something very simple:

Make a custom version of android that boots up, hands control over to the kernel, and then displays a very simple kiosk menu system and does not enter normal android.

I’m looking in the directory `system/core/init/` for the right entry point but I’m not sure of the right spot.

Where would be the easiest place to hack into normal android kernel startup?

Comment: Are you able to boot up your compiled android?

Comment: Why not just running your kiosk app as the launcher? That would allow you to boot into your custom kiosk menu system without making any nasty hacks.